# How to get bootstrap to work in Eclipse?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get `bootstrap` to work with `eclipse Dynamic Web Project (Helios)`. However when I run (Tomcat v7) on the server I get regular html. I think there must be an error with the link. I downloaded bootstrap and imported the file system in WebContent, there is a bootstrap folder (with css, img, js) inside WebContent.

I have tried:

```
"href="boostrap/css/bootstrap.css". "href="WebContent/boostrap/css/bootstrap.css". "href="css/bootstrap.css". "href=bootstrap.css".
```

I also copied the bootstrap folder outside of WebContent and tried all of the above. What's wrong?

The code I used is exactly (copied and pasted) the source from http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/#
with the href modified. I did not put it here because I'm getting weird formatting from StackOverflow.

Comment: can you give us your link to your site?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you spelled boostrap instead of bootstrap when using "href...?

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same problem. When I am using eclipse server to run webpage(using bootstrap) then it doesn't work.
But if i go to the webroot or webcontent folder and open the webpage then bootstrap works fine.
I hope you have downloaded jquery.min.js.